# simplexml_load_file : iterate and separate node with attribute

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am completely unsure about the title for this, so sorry, here is my problem :

I am iterating through my xml and declaring variables out of it. It works fine, and looks like this :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('path/to/myxml.xml');
$bay0 = $xml->xpath("//Car[@park='0'  and contains(Group, '$filter')]");

foreach($bay0 as $vehicle) {
    $brand = $vehicle->Brand;
    $model = $vehicle->Model;
    $equips = $vehicle->Equipments
    [...]
 }
```

and so on.

In my xml, there are equipments for these cars. Equipments can have the attribute `type="1"` or `type="2"` like this :

```
 <Equipments>
      <Equipment type="1">automatic doors</Equipment>
      <Equipment type="2">full led headlights</Equipment>
  </Equipments>
```

I want to be able to separate equipments as two different variables in my foreach, depending of their type, but I did not find an answer to this, partly because I can't even properly formulate what I'm looking for.

Thanks for your help.

Edit :

Adding example of what I'm looking for :

```
  foreach($bay0 as $vehicle) {
    $brand = $vehicle->Brand;
    $model = $vehicle->Model;
    $equips1 = $vehicle->Equipments[type="1"];
    $equips2 = $vehicle->Equipments[type="2"];
 }
```

Comment: Look into the docs for `attributes()` http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php ... should help out.

Comment: If you can't describe what you're looking for, we're going to struggle to help you. Can you show some example of what result you're looking for?

Comment: @Randall Unless you're using namespaces, or looping over all attributes of an element, you shouldn't need the `->attributes()` method; you can use the `$element['attribute']` shorthand instead, e.g. `$equipment['type']`.

Comment: I was only pointing to the full way which is the more compatible method... after one learns the hard way, they can look for shorthand ways ;)

Comment: I edited my question with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could help you

```
foreach($bay0 as $vehicle) {
    $brand = $vehicle->Brand;
    $model = $vehicle->Model;

    $equips=[];//start a array
    if($vehicle->Equipments[0]['type']=='1'){
        $equips[1] = $vehicle->Equipments;
    //$equips[1][] = $vehicle->Equipments; if many
    }
    elseif($vehicle->Equipments[0]['type']=='2'){
        $equips[2] = $vehicle->Equipments;
    //$equips[2][] = $vehicle->Equipments; if many
    }
[...]
 }
```

Comment: I must be missing something in here, I get a NULL from trying to output these.

Comment: Please try it now, was left [0]/attribute array